# How to spool everything from a column in SQL

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm making a PS script that calls a sql*plus script and then send the file by mail.

Yet the issue is the result exported in the CSV is truncated at the last column because it's an xml and there is a line break between each markup

On Oracle SQL the results are in a single line.

In the csv with only these as options :

```
SET lines 2500;
SET pages 1;
```

The output of the spool file at the column 'info' looks like this :

```
'<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
<error_response>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  <id>8cad0277-3a60-4cfd-a9c4-c272f69038ce</id>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  <timestamp>2023-03-23T09:25:03.001Z</timestamp>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  <error_lang>EN</error_lang>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <error_type>MULE:UNKNOWN</error_type>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  <error_code>520</error_code>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  <error_msg>
```

Now what i want is everything to be in a single line

I have tried severals things but it truncate it up to the `520 - '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`

Here are all the things i tried :

```
SET Wrap OFF;
SET Longchunksize 90000;
SET Pagesize 0;
SET lin[esize] 5000;
SET TrimSpool ON;
SET long 2000000;
SET lines 32737;
column info format a120
```

None worked still getting truncated to the 520 xml
How can i get all the data contained in the info column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line breaks are in your data, SQL*Plus isn't adding them. You need to replace line breaks with some special character that cannot appear in your data, then once you get the data to its final destination, replace them with line breaks to restore the formatted look.

I like to use non-printing control characters nobody ever sees:

Upon extract:

```
SELECT REPLACE(info,CHR(10),CHR(21)) info
  FROM ...
```

At the final destination:

```
INSERT INTO target
SELECT REPLACE(info,CHR(21),CHR(10))
  FROM ...
```

Also make sure you set linesize really big, which you have.